# python multiprocessing spawn method's conflict when _fixup_main_from_path() is called

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

experts,

I am using python's multiprocessing's spawn method to spawn child processes.
The child process is a function call.

One issue that recently get notified is when child process is created,
it will try to import all the import statement from main module via the call to _fixup_main_from_path()
I actually don't need those import statements at all.
It is causing conflicts in my child processes.

I am considering moving away from multiprocessing and use subprocess. Subprocess has its own problem though: it does not support functional call so I have to package the executable as a binary instead of a shared library. So there are some additional work there.
My question would be,

1. is there any way that we don't call _fixup_main_from_path for multiprocessing spawn method.
2. Or for subprocessing, can I do a functional call instead of launching as an executable?.
3. Any other alternatives?
   Thanks a lot.

Update: I drafted an sample code for my situation.
There are three files involved in this example.
I only have access to one of the file my_lib.py
There is something bad in file1.py but I don't have control over it.

```
file1.py: 
import x1
# do something bad like call 
folly::symbolizer::addFatalSignalCallback() # c++ in pybind



### my_lib.py: 
import multiprocessing
def my_runner():
    # run my awesome application 
    folly::symbolizer::addFatalSignalCallback() # c++ in pybind 
def run_my_awesome_application():
    process = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Process(
        target= my_runner
    ) # multiprocessing.spawn._fixup_main_from_path is called.
    process.start()

## main.py:
import file1
import my_lib

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_my_awesome_application()
```

Comment: shift the problematic imports under the `if __name__ ...` clause

Comment: thanks a lot for comments. 
Unfortunately I don't have control on those, as I only own this code as a library for other people to use. People use my library inside which we call multiprocessing spawn to spin up child process. Is there anything I can do before calling mutiprocessing spawn, which I have control?

Comment: I don't get you, are the problematic imports inside a library you don't have control over? In that case you might be out of luck, importing the `__main__` module is necessary if the start method is `spawn`.

Comment: I don't get it either. Presumably you have control over the script you are writing. If you put all of its import statements within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, then with the *spawn* method they will not be imported by child processes unless they are explicitly being imported by those child processes anyway. But *those* imports shouldn't be problematic. Perhaps you could post some code that explains your problem in greater detail.

Comment: thanks. my situation is I am an infra developer. Others use my library to develop their scripts. I don't own main nor I own any of the imported files. The import is transitive and sometime hit this side effect. It seems I might have to switch to use subprocess instead of using multiprocessing.

Comment: @BaozhenChen What is the exact nature of the conflict?

Comment: @Booboo thanks for following up. The nature of the conflict is in the main module some module called this FatalSignalCallbackRegistry in the __init__.py file https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/main/folly/experimental/symbolizer/SignalHandler.cpp#L55 
In the child process we need to call FatalSignalCallbackRegistry again. But it can only be called once.

We have also seen some other cases but this one is most problematic. We have some nasty workaround to get around for this issue. But we are mainly concerned it might show up again in other format. We like multiprocessing beside this.

Comment: @BaozhenChen Since you are using the *spawn* method, could you have in your library module something like `import implib; imp.reload(init)` to reload *init.py* (or whatever module name directly causes the `FatalSignalCallbackRegistry` object to be created)? This code would be in an `if __name__ == '__mp_main__':` block so that it is only executed by the child process and executed prior to your calling the `FatalSignalCallbackRegistry` object.

Comment: @Booboo I was able to update the question with an example code. 
Can you help to take a further look at it?

Comment: I confess that I am not familiar with the use of double colon (`::`) in the following context: `folly::symbolizer::addFatalSignalCallback()` (I have only seen `::` used in slices). How does `addFatalSignalCallback` get imported? Are you not showing a necessary `import` statement?

Comment: If it the import of `x1` that is loading `addFatalSignalCallback`, then I would have in *my_lib.py* `if __name__ == '__mp_main__':  import implib; implib.reload(x1)`.

Comment: @Booboo oops. the double :: is just something I copied from c++ directly as the code is actually in c++ porting over from pybind. Sorry for make this confuse as I didn't include the wrapper to make it simple, only annotating at line end.

Comment: thanks. adding 
if __name__ == '__mp_main__':  import implib; implib.reload(x1).
should work. 
however, it is less likely to pass code review as an Infra code. 
We don't want to my_lib.py to depend on file1.py or x1.py.

maybe I have to switch to subprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

You said: **We don't want my_lib.py to depend on file1.py or x1.py.**

Your module already depends on *x1.py* because you need to import it so that you can call `addFataSignalCallback`. So *that* should not be an issue. Not wanting a dependence on *file1.py* is understandable. If you are concerned about whether *whatever* script that is importing *my_lib.py* may have caused  *x1.py* to be imported and therefore there may have also already been a call to `addFatalSignalCallback`, then the following code will do a regular import of `x1` if it has not already been imported or it will reload x1 on the assumption that `addFatalSignalCallback()` has been called by whoever imported `x1`:

```py
import multiprocessing

def my_runner():
    # I am assuming that this function is only called from within this
    # module and as a spawned child process.
    # Therefore, we know  __name__ must be '__mp_main__' and so
    # there is no need to check this. Otherwise, modify the following
    # if statement to add `and __name__ == '__mp_main__'` to the condition:
    if 'x1' in globals() and  globals()['x1'].__class__.__name__ == 'module':
        # module x1 has already been loaded
        import implib
        implib.reload(x1)
    else:
        # module x1 has not been loaded
        import x1

    # run my awesome application 
    addFatalSignalCallback() 

def run_my_awesome_application():
    process = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Process(
        target= my_runner
    )
    process.start()
```